# PageControll error number of page swift 4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

I created a PageController with 3 pages .. I allocated and declared everything, I implemented the two functions that allow scrolling views, in the same I entered the commands to enable the controller with the right page reported. the result is that if I flow my pages is all ok, while under the page counter works as he wants.. and I can not understand what is wrong

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9DQa.jpg)[problem2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msiD0.jpg)[problem3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JapYO.jpg)

```
        import UIKit
        import AVFoundation
        protocol IntroNavigationDelegate: class {
            func showNextViewController()
            func showPreviousViewController()
            var isPagingEnabled: Bool { get set }
        }
        final class IntroViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, IntroNavigationDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {   
            func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
                if let viewControllerIndex = self.displayedControllers.index(of: viewController) {
                    if viewControllerIndex == 0 {
                    } else if viewControllerIndex == 1 {
                        return self.displayedControllers[viewControllerIndex - 1]
                    }
                }
                return nil
            }

            func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
                if let viewControllerIndex = self.displayedControllers.index(of: viewController) {

                    if viewControllerIndex < self.displayedControllers.count - 1 {
                        self.pageControl.currentPage = 1
                        return self.displayedControllers[viewControllerIndex + 1]
                    } else {
                        self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
                    }
                }
                return nil
            }

            var introRouter: IntroRouter?

            var pageControl = UIPageControl()

            var displayedControllers: [UIViewController] = []

            private var scrollView: UIScrollView? {
                for view in view.subviews {
                    if let subView = view as? UIScrollView {
                        return subView
                    }
                }
                return nil
            }

            var isPagingEnabled: Bool {
                get {
                    return scrollView?.isScrollEnabled ?? true
                }
                set {
                    scrollView?.isScrollEnabled = newValue
                }
            }

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                configurePageControl()
                setupUI()
                self.pageControl.updateCurrentPageDisplay()
                arrangeSubviews()
                self.delegate = self
            }

            override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
                self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
            }

            override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
                super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
                navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
            }

            func setDiplayedControllers(_ controllers: [UIViewController], visualizedController: UIViewController) {
                displayedControllers = controllers
                setViewControllers([visualizedController], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }

            func showNextViewController() {
                if let current = viewControllers?.first, let next = IntroViewController(self, viewControllerAfter: current) {
                    setViewControllers([next], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }

            func showPreviousViewController() {
                if let current = viewControllers?.first, let previous = IntroViewController(self, viewControllerBefore: current) {
                    setViewControllers([previous], direction: .reverse, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }

            func configurePageControl(){
                self.pageControl.frame = CGRect()
                self.pageControl.numberOfPages = self.displayedControllers.count
                self.pageControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                self.pageControl.updateCurrentPageDisplay()

                self.view.addSubview(self.pageControl)
                pageControl.activate([
                    pageControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
                    pageControl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.1),
                    pageControl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1),
                    ])
            }

            override init(transitionStyle style: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation, options: [String : Any]? = nil) {
                super.init(transitionStyle: style, navigationOrientation: navigationOrientation, options: options)
                setup()
            }

            func setRouter(introRouter: IntroRouter) {
                self.introRouter = introRouter
            }

            required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
                fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
            }

            private func setup() {
                view.backgroundColor = .white
                dataSource = self
            }
        }

        private extension IntroViewController {

                func IntroViewController(_ IntroViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

                    if let viewControllerIndex = self.displayedControllers.index(of: viewController) {
                        if viewControllerIndex == 0 {
                            // wrap to last page in array
                            return self.displayedControllers.last
                        } else {
                            // go to previous page in array
                            return self.displayedControllers[viewControllerIndex + 1]
                        }
                    }
                    return nil
                }

                func IntroViewController(_ IntroViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
                    self.pageControl.updateCurrentPageDisplay()
                    if let viewControllerIndex = self.displayedControllers.index(of: viewController) {
                        if viewControllerIndex < self.displayedControllers.count - 1 {
                            // go to next page in array
                            self.pageControl.currentPage = viewControllerIndex
                            return self.displayedControllers[viewControllerIndex + 1]
                        } else {
                            // wrap to first page in array
                            self.pageControl.currentPage = viewControllerIndex
                            return self.displayedControllers.first
                        }
                    }
                    return nil
                }

            func IntroViewController(_ IntroViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {

        //         set the pageControl.currentPage to the index of the current viewController in pages
                if let viewControllers = IntroViewController.viewControllers {
                    if let viewControllerIndex = self.displayedControllers.index(of: viewControllers[0]) {
                        self.pageControl.currentPage = viewControllerIndex
                        self.pageControl.updateCurrentPageDisplay()
                    }
                }
            }

            func setupUI() {
                configurePageControl()
                pageControl.do {
                    $0.numberOfPages = 3
        //            $0.currentPage = 0
                    $0.pageIndicatorTintColor = .lightGray
                    $0.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = Theme.Colors.white
                    $0.currentPage = self.displayedControllers.count
                }
            }

            func arrangeSubviews() {
                view.addSubview(pageControl)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try the below code. It would be helpfull.

```
class PageViewModel: NSObject {

    private var timer: Timer?
    private var interval: Double?
    var enableAutoScroll: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            self.toggleTimer()
        }
    }
    var viewControllers: [UIViewController]
    var currentIndex: Int = 0
    var direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection = .forward

    init(viewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
        self.viewControllers = viewControllers
        super.init()
    }

    override convenience init() {
        self.init(viewControllers: [])
    }

    private func stopTimer() {
        if self.timer != nil {
            timer?.invalidate()
            timer = nil
            return
        }
    }

    private func startTimer() {

        if self.timer != nil {
            return
        }

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            if let time = interval {
                timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: time, repeats: true, block: { (timer: Timer) in
                    self.timerFire()
                })
            }
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            if let time = interval {
                timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: time, target: self, selector: #selector(PageViewModel.timerFire), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            }
        }
    }

    @objc private func timerFire() {
        if direction == .forward {
            var index = currentIndex
            if index < self.viewControllers.count - 1 {
                index += 1
            } else {
                index = 0
            }

            currentIndex = index
            scrollToNextPage?(currentIndex)
            pageNumberChangedObserver?(currentIndex)

        } else {

            var index = currentIndex
            if index <= 0 {
                index = (self.viewControllers.count - 1)
            } else {
                index -= 1
            }
            currentIndex = index
            scrollToNextPage?(index)
            pageNumberChangedObserver?(currentIndex)
        }
    }


    // MARK: - Timer
    func toggleTimer() {
        if enableAutoScroll == true {
            startTimer()
        } else {
            stopTimer()
        }
    }

    fileprivate var scrollToNextPage: ((_ index: Int) -> Void)?
    func scrollToNextPage(callBack: @escaping (_ index: Int) -> Void) {
        scrollToNextPage = callBack
    }

    // MARK: - PageNumberChangedObserver
    fileprivate var pageNumberChangedObserver: ((_ index: Int) -> Void)?
    func pageNumberChanged(callBack: @escaping (_ index: Int) -> Void) {
        pageNumberChangedObserver = callBack
    }

}

// MARK: - UIPageViewControllerDataSource
extension PageViewModel: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let viewControllerIndex = viewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }
        let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

        // User is on the first view controller and swiped left to loop to
        // the last view controller.
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
            //return orderedViewControllers.last
            // Uncommment the line below, remove the line above if you don't want the page control to loop.
            return nil
        }

        guard viewControllers.count > previousIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        return viewControllers[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = viewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }

        let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
        let orderedViewControllersCount = viewControllers.count

        // User is on the last view controller and swiped right to loop to
        // the first view controller.
        guard orderedViewControllersCount != nextIndex else {
            //return orderedViewControllers.first
            // Uncommment the line below, remove the line above if you don't want the page control to loop.
            return nil
        }

        guard orderedViewControllersCount > nextIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        return viewControllers[nextIndex]
    }

}

// MARK: - UIPageViewControllerDelegate
extension PageViewModel: UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {

        if let pageContentViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers?[0] {

            if let index = viewControllers.index(of: pageContentViewController) {
                currentIndex = index
                pageNumberChangedObserver?(currentIndex)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Write below code in your Container View Controller: -

```
    // set current page to the page controller
    func setNextPage(index: Int, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection) {

        if let firstViewController = pageViewModel?.viewControllers[selectedCategoryCell] {
            pageViewController?.setViewControllers([firstViewController],
                                                   direction: direction,
                                                   animated: true,
                                                   completion: nil)
        }
    }


 // MARK: - SET PAGE CONTROLLER's VIEW's
    private func setupPageViewController() {
        let pageViewController: UIPageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
        pageViewController.dataSource = pageViewModel
        pageViewController.delegate = pageViewModel
        if let firstViewController = pageViewModel?.viewControllers[selectedCategoryCell] {
            pageViewController.setViewControllers([firstViewController],
                                                  direction: .forward,
                                                  animated: true,
                                                  completion: nil)
        }

        for recognizer in pageViewController.gestureRecognizers {
            if recognizer is UITapGestureRecognizer {
                recognizer.isEnabled = false
            }
        }
        self.addChildViewController(pageViewController)
        self.containerView.addSubview(pageViewController.view)
        var pageViewRect = self.containerView.bounds
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            pageViewRect = pageViewRect.insetBy(dx: 40.0, dy: 40.0)
        }
        pageViewController.view.frame = pageViewRect
        pageViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        self.pageViewController = pageViewController
    }


    // set the selected page and accordingly set the above collection view ( that is treatment option's collection view)
    func pageNumberChanged(index: Int) {
        self.selectedCategoryCell = index
    }

    // MARK: Init View Controller for Page Controller
    func initViewController(index: Int) -> UIViewController {
        guard let itemsViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MatchesV2ViewController") as? MatchesV2ViewController else {
            fatalError("Items View Controller Not Found")
        }
        itemsViewController.delegate = self
        itemsViewController.currentMatch = matches.user[index]
        return itemsViewController
    }

    // MARK: Setting VC In Page View Controller
    func instantiateViewControllers() {
        matchesScreen.removeAll()
        for i in 0..<matches.user.count {
            matchesScreen.append(initViewController(index: i))
        }
        pageViewModel = PageViewModel(viewControllers: matchesScreen)
        pageViewModel?.pageNumberChanged(callBack: { (index: Int) in
            self.pageNumberChanged(index: index)
        })
        pageViewModel?.scrollToNextPage(callBack: { (index: Int) in
            self.setNextPage(index: index, direction: .forward)
        })
        if matchesScreen.count > 0 {
            self.setupPageViewController()
        }
    }
```

Comment: I need only the part that manages the pagecontroller, I do not want to redo everything .. the rest is working

Comment: I think this is the perfect way to handle the UIPageController.

Comment: of my code that I wrote what should I delete to use yours?

Comment: My code is divided into two parts. First part just write in  Pageview.Swift that contain handling of UIPageController  delegate and DataSource. Just like UITableViewDelegate and dataSource.                                                                and Second Part Contain how to use that function. like set DataSource to UIPageController, Moving Next PageController